# Get already existing Instance of Controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I am writing a javafx application which manages simple entities like customer, booking and bill. For the gui i defined following fxml which is my main gui:

```
<TabPane fx:id="mainTabPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="698.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.MainController">
    <tabs>
        <Tab id="BoxTab" fx:id="boxManagementTab" text="Box Management">
            <content>
                <fx:include source="boxTab.fxml"/>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Booking">
            <content>
                <fx:include source="bookingTab.fxml"/>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Bill" >
            <content>
                <fx:include source="billTab.fxml"/>
            </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

In these tabs there are just **Tableviews** which show basic Data. Every Tab has it's own controller. The Problem i am facing is that i for example want to delete bookings when they appear on a new bill. This means i need to set new Data to the **Tableview** of Booking.

I wanted to Access the TableView of Booking over the Controller of Booking in the bill Controller by using FXMLLoader and the load() method. But as far as i know, with everytime you use load() a new instance of the controller is created.
So is there any way how to access the already existing instance of a controller, which gets initiated after the ?
I wanted to do this by loading the controller of this Tab.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers#t=201703201252299188006.

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the `FXMLLoader` instance, you can simply call `FXMLLoader#getController()` to get the created controller instance. If you need to acces the controller lateron in the programs lifecycle than make sure you assign it to a field.

([Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController--))

Comment: ok, i thought about that. But i do not use the FXMLLoader load() method, because the tab gets loaded in my main.fxml file with <fx:include> as shown in the code snippet above. Is there maybe a way i can acces the loader the <fx:include> tab uses?

Comment: In that case, Im pretty sure you aren't able to acces the controller in any way, unless you take care of the tab loading in your code somewhere.

Comment: How to do this is pretty clearly laid out in the [Fxml documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers). I can dig out other links when I am back at my computer.